# r: character matching with dictionary word position

Tags: r, string, character, map-matching

I have two **dataframes**,

`word_table <- 
               word_9   word_1   word_3   ...word_random
               word_2     na        na    ...word_random
               word_5   word_3      na    ...word_random`

`dictionary_words <- 
                    word_2
                    word_3
                    word_4
                    word_6
                    word_7
                    word_8
                    word_9
                       .
                       .
                       .
                    word_n`

what I am looking for, matching the `word_table` with the `dictionary_words` and replacing the words with the word position available in the dictionary, like this,

`result <- 
           7      na     2    ...
           1      na     na   ...
           na     2      na   ...`

I have tried `pmatch`, `charmatch`, `match` functions, that returning `result` right way when the `dictionary_words` are in smaller length, but when it is relatively long like more than 20000 words, the `result` is coming only for first column, and rest of the columns are just becoming `na` like this.

`result <- 
           7      na     na   ...
           1      na     na   ...
           na     na     na   ...`

**is there any other way I can do character matching, like using any apply function**?

sample

```
word_table <- data.frame(word_1 <- c("conflict","", "resolved", "", "", ""), word_2 <- c("", "one", "tricky", "one", "", "one"), 
                 word_3 <- c("thanks","", "", "comments", "par",""),word_4 <- c("thanks","", "", "comments", "par",""), word_5 <- c("", "one", "tricky", "one", "", "one"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(word_table) <- c("word_1", "word_2", "word_3", "word_4", "word_5")
## Targeted Words
dictionary_words <- data.frame(cbind(c("abovementioned","abundant","conflict", "thanks", "tricky", "one", "two", "three","four", "resolved")))

## convert into matrix (if needed)
word_table <- as.matrix(word_table)
dictionary_words <- as.matrix(dictionary_words)

## pmatch for each of the element in the dataframe (dt)
# matched_table <- pmatch(dt, TargetWord)
# dim(matched_table) <- dim(dt)
# print(matched_table) 

result <- `dim<-`(pmatch(word_table, dictionary_words, duplicates.ok=TRUE), dim(word_table))
print(result) # working fine, but when the dictionary_words is large, returning result for only first column of the word_table
```

Comment: welcome! it's a good idea to post your question along with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: Can you show your code?  Have you tried `"dim<-"(match(as.matrix(word_table), dictionary_words[,1]), dim(word_table))`

Comment: thanks vincent, it is actually hard for me to show a reproducible example, because as I have mentioned, when I am working with relatively small dataframe, it is working perfectly. but when working with large dataframe, it is returning only first column result. please find a sample as I have edited.

Comment: You don't need `data.frame(cbind` , just `data.frame(V1 = c(...` is enough.  Also it is better to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to avoid the column to be converted to `factor`

Comment: Can you post the `str` of the original dataset.

Comment: Thanks akrun, I have tried that as well, probably I had read your answer in another post. the method is working fine when dataframe is small, `dictionary_words` especially smaller. for large `dictionary_words` only returning result for first column. :(

Comment: `str(small_word_table)
 chr [1:6, 1:5] "conflict" "" "resolved" "" "" "" "" "one" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "word_1" "word_2" "word_3" "word_4" ...`
> str(large_word_table)
 chr [1:79, 1:50] "conflict" "" "thanks" "" "" "conflict" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:50] "aaa_first" "aaa_2" "aaa_3" "aaa_4" ...

Comment: `str(TargetWord_small_word_dictionary)
 chr [1:10, 1] "abovementioned" "abundant" "conflict" "thanks" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "cbind.c..abovementioned....abundant....conflict....thanks....tricky..."`
> str(large_word_dictionary)
 chr [1:13901, 1] "abba" "ability" "abovementioned" "absolute" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "TargetWord"

Comment: both are same, just size is different. I guess the character match has some limitations

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bipul-mohanto/9b6a960955419f8cb689cf2c32edcff1 please find the file here

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible example:

```
 word_table <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("word_2", 
                                                    "word_5", "word_9"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                             NA, 2L), .Label = c("word_1", "word_3"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                          NA, NA), .Label = "word_3", class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L), .Label = "...word_random", class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ))

 dictionary_words <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:7, .Label = c("word_2", "word_3", 
                                                              "word_4", "word_6", "word_7", "word_8", "word_9"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                        -7L))
```

You can use `sapply` :

```
> sapply(word_table, function(x) match(x, dictionary_words[, 1]))
     V1 V2 V3 V4
[1,]  7 NA  2 NA
[2,]  1 NA NA NA
[3,] NA  2 NA NA
```

or `apply` if you prefer:

```
> apply(word_table, 2, function(x) match(x, dictionary_words[, 1]))
V1 V2 V3 V4
[1,]  7 NA  2 NA
[2,]  1 NA NA NA
[3,] NA  2 NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks vincent once more, Perfectly working on the sample dataframe I mentioned above. but same thing happening when `word_table` is `79x50` and `dictionary_words` is `20000x1`, the result is just coming for first column, rest all are becoming `NA`

Comment: could you paste the result of `dput(word_table)`  and `dput(dictionnary_words)` somewhere, eg in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) ?

Comment: hello vincent, sorry...i am new here, so little slow. hope u will find the files in github, https://gist.github.com/bipul-mohanto/9b6a960955419f8cb689cf2c32edcff1

Comment: it worked fine but many of the words in `word_table` are not present in `dictionnary_words`, try the following: `unique(word_table[, 1]) %in% dictionary_words` !

Comment: also, most words have space(s) in them, `word_table <- gsub(" *", "", word_table)` should help.

Comment: Vincent, you are a true life saver. Problem solved. I do not have enough point to give u up vote, but I really appreciate your help. God bless you